# Eigenvalues of the sum of Laplacian matrix and the all ones matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, laplacian

Given an undirected graph and its Laplacian is $L$.
I need to find the eigenvalues of the sum: $L + \mathbf{11^T}$ (where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all-ones vector, which means that $\mathbf{11^T}$ is a matrix constructed only by ones).

I know that 0 is no more an eigenvalue, and its "replacement" is $n$ (where $L$ is of size $n \times n$. The reason is that the sum of the rows of the new matrix is $n$). Using matlab I found that the other eigenvalues don't change, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Thanks,

JayJay

Comment: The all ones vector is an eigenvector......

Comment: That's true. This is the only common eigenvector with respect to the $0$ eigenvalue of $L$ and to $n$ eigenvalue of the new matrix. What does it say about the OTHER eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $0$ eigenspace of $J$ (the usual name for the matrix of all ones) is orthogonal to the non-zero eigenspace. In particular, every nontrivial eigenvector of $L$ is also an eigenvector of $J.$ So, $(L+J)v = Lv + Jv = Lv,$ so the eigenvalues don't change.

Comment: Just to make sure, the 0 eigenspace means the eigenspace related to the eigenvalue = $0$ or $J$, and the non-zero is the one related to the $n$ eigenvalue?
Also, I am don't completely understand why every nontrivial eigenvector of $L$ is an eigenvector of $J$... If this is true the proof is trivial.

Comment: Yes, for the first. For the second, note that the vector of all $1$s is an eigenvector of both $L$ and $J$ and (by self-adjointness) every eigenvector of $L$ is orthogonal to it, hence in the $0$ eigenspace of $J.$